# CPU Flame Graphs for Python

Tags: python, c, performance, linux-kernel, visualization

Brendan Gregg's [CPU Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html) are a way of visualising CPU usage over a period of time based on call stacks.

His [FlameGraph github project](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) provides a language-independent way to plot these graphs:

For each language, FlameGraph requires a way of providing stack input in the form of lines like this:

```
grandparent_func;parent_func;func 42
```

This means that the instrumented program was observed running function `func`, where that was called from `parent_func`, in turn called from top-level function `grandparent_func`.  It says that call stack was observed 42 times.

How can I gather stack information from Python programs and provide it to FlameGraph?

For bonus points: How can that be extended so that both the C and Python stack is shown, or even down to the kernel on Linux (in a similar way to some of the Java and node.js flame graphs on Brendan's website)?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to do something with dtrace - requires an OS that supports dtrace and a patched version of python.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my opinion, the prettiness of flame-graphs exceeds their usefulness for finding speedups, and there's a way that's less pretty but more effective. [*Explained here.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771)

Comment: user5402: last I heard dtrace was not suitable for production use on Linux

Comment: Mike Dunlavey: I don't disagree but I think all's fair with finding performance problems, so I'd like to try flame graphs too

Comment: perf script [-s [Python]:script[.py] ], but linux kernel should build with special flag (NO_LIBPYTHON=0) like describe here http://askubuntu.com/questions/577768/how-can-i-make-perf-script-g-python-work

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can try [`sys.setprofile`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile), which is the core for the standard python profiler [`profile`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/profile.py) and [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile). This method sets a hook to the "call" and "return" events of every function, including those functions of C-API.

> The system’s profile function is called similarly to the system’s trace function (see settrace()), but it isn’t called for each executed line of code (only on call and return, but the return event is reported even when an exception has been set).

Below is a working example:

```
from time import clock 
t0 = clock()

def getFun(frame):
    code = frame.f_code 
    return  code.co_name+' in '+code.co_filename+':'+str(code.co_firstlineno)

def trace_dispatch(frame, event, arg):
    if event in [ "c_call" , 'call', 'return', 'c_return']:
        t = int((clock()-t0)*1000)
        f = frame
        stack=[]
        while(f):
          stack.insert( 0,getFun(f) )
          f = f.f_back
        print event, '\t', '; '.join(stack), '; ', t

import sys
sys.setprofile(trace_dispatch)
try:
    execfile('test.py')
finally:
    sys.setprofile(None)
```

Test.py

```
def f(x):
    return x+1
def main(x):
    return f(x)
main(10)
```

This will print out

```
c_call    0
call      <module> in test.py:2 ;  1
call      <module> in test.py:2; main in test.py:5 ;  1
call      <module> in test.py:2; main in test.py:5; f in test.py:2 ;  5
return    <module> in test.py:2; main in test.py:5; f in test.py:2 ;  8
return    <module> in test.py:2; main in test.py:5 ;  11
return    <module> in test.py:2 ;  14
c_return  18
c_call    21
```

See a more comprehensive profiling function [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/465831-profiling-threads/).

#### C stack in python

You cannot access  the C stack within the python interpreter. It is necessary to use a debugger or profiler that supports C/C++. I would recommand [gdb python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb).

Comment: Thank you for all this information - this is helpful

Comment: This is great, but I think it doesn't *quite* answer the question, for the trivial but important reason that I think it doesn't produce output of the form that FlameGraph wants

Comment: @gdlmx Right.  Me neither

Answer (score 3):

[Pyflame](https://github.com/uber/pyflame) supports plotting flame graphs in two formats (either the 'traditional' form as in the question, or chrome's 'sideways' flame graphs, using chrome itself).

From https://github.com/uber/pyflame:

```
# Attach to PID 12345 and profile it for 1 second
pyflame -p 12345

# Attach to PID 768 and profile it for 5 seconds, sampling every 0.01 seconds
pyflame -s 5 -r 0.01 -p 768

# Run py.test against tests/, emitting sample data to prof.txt
pyflame -o prof.txt -t py.test tests/
```