# Is callgrind able to include kernel functions in the call graph?

Tags: profiling, valgrind, call-graph, callgrind

I am looking for a tool that generates the call graph for an application and includes the kernel functions as well. More specifically, I'm interested to know how many times a function was called. Is there a way to do that with callgrind? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: Are you doing this because your objective is to make your code run faster? If that is your goal, it is of little value to get a call graph, or see into kernel functions, or count how many times they are called. [*Here are some reasons why.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771) If you want to know what *does* work, [*try this.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). There's also a [*crude video.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U) Here's [*another explication that might be helpful.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771)