# Hexadecimal function name in gproftools profiling

Tags: hex, profiling, aslr, gperftools

After CPU profiling using gproftools (google profiler) it show some function name as hexadecimal values.

According to last comment of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-perftools/7sdO7wrPUpE the problem looks like caused by [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)
But I did not understand why few function names are hexadecimal value while other are normal.

Sample Output of profiling.

16  0.40%   86.80%  16  0.40%   00007f05e018bc5d

16  0.40%   87.20%  36  0.90%   _IO_file_xsgetn

16  0.40%   87.60%  16  0.40%   __memcpy_sse2

16  0.40%   88.00%  16  0.40%   __tls_get_addr

15  0.40%   88.40%  15  0.40%   __GI___libc_free

15  0.40%   88.70%  15  0.40%   __GI_strlen

Comment: [*maybe helpful answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771)

Comment: Tarinder Singh, what is your OS? Hex is there because pprof was unable to resolve address with `addr2line` tool.

Comment: RHEL 7, 
but is was giving correct OUTPUT on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use latest version of pprof. There was bug that we fixed couple releases ago that added support for -fPIE (position independent executable).