# Node JS discovering slow async calls

Tags: node.js, performance, asynchronous, profiling

Is their anyway to generate a flame graph or similar that includes time of async calls? To help in hunting down slow ones

Comment: [*This post*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771) talks about flame graphs and a method that works just fine, with or without async calls.