# How to find top 10 slowest functions in node.js? Profiling node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, profiling, v8

Node.JS and V8 provides some advanced tools for profiling, but I'm looking for **something very simple**.

How to run a script, and when it finishes - **print top 10 slowest functions** that took most CPU time?

Comment: Back up and don't ask for "slowest functions". Ask ***why*** is it spending time. Then there is a [*very simple way to find out*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771).

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation even has "simple profiling" in the URL: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Have you tried that?