# Construct flamegraph with start and end timestamps

Tags: performance, profiling, flamegraph

i am collecting profile with custom instrumentation of each function and the format is simple. Each line in the profile dump has the following data:

```
symbol address, start time, end time
```

Is it possible to convert this to a format consumable by flamegraph charting tool? What are the formats consumed by a framegraph charting tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) No, because flamegraphs need call stacks, and b) flamegraphs are pretty but useless for finding speedups. Speed problems easily [*hide in them*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771), and they usually ignore I/O. Also [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771).

Comment: is it possible to construct call stacks from the timestamps assuming everything is single threaded?

Comment: No, because at the time of entering or exiting a routine you don't know where it was called from. Listen, forget flame graphs. They are popular because they are pretty, but little else. What you need is stack samples (line-of-code level) taken at random wall-clock times, which the user can see, not summarized. They will lead directly to whatever is costing time.

Comment: assuming single threaded application, the call sequence will be chronological. so as long as a function `foo` is within the [start time, end time] bounds of another function `bar`, can we not safely say `bar` calls `foo`... transitively?

Comment: @A.K. I suppose. It would be a chore figuring out what the hierarchy is.