# how to profile blocking code in java – measure execution time instead of CPU time

Tags: java, profiling, jfr

I am trying to profile that is often blocking in either database and rest calls. The code is not cpu bound. The following sample junit methods should illustrate the issue:

```
@RepeatedTest(10)
void fast() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

@RepeatedTest(10)
void slow() throws InterruptedException {
    // imagine a slow database or rest call or any other blocking code
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I am using IntelliJ and Java Flight Recorder. I expect that method `fast` is reported as using about 10% of execution time and method `slow` is using about 90% of execution time. But they are not reported at all because they don't eat CPU time.

How can I profile the real execution time that includes waiting time in blocking code instead of CPU time only?

Comment: It's very common to think what you need to do is measure the time. **No.** What you need to do is *locate* the problem. The exact percentage doesn't matter. [*Here's how.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/317160/23771)

Comment: Using thread dumps can help of course. But they give me less information and they are harder to read compared to a flame graph of a properly configured profiler.

Comment: Here's the [*problem with flame-graphs.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771)

Answer (score 3):

Async profiler is an excellent, free, and very lightweight tool for JVM profiling. In typical settings, it indeed measures on-CPU time but it has an option to do "Wall-clock" profiling: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler#wall-clock-profiling

You can experiment with that and see if that gives you better results.

Comment: Your suggestion does indeed help with profiling. I still have problems as it reports the main threads as eating only 1.82% of all time which makes finding my own code in the main thread hard. I'd expect a much higher value. But the relative results within the scope of my code are much more useful to me compared to CPU profiling.

Answer (score 2):

You need a profiler that understands the semantics of JDBC and HTTP calls. For example, with JProfiler, the profiling agent captures a synthetic Net I/O thread state that is included when the thread status selector is set to "All states".

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: JProfiler solves the issue indeed.