# How do one visualize gprof profiling data as a flamegraph?

Tags: c++, profiling, gprof, flamegraph

I've profiled a C++ application using [GNU gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/index.html). It would be really nice to visualize the data and for that purpose I found a python utility gprof2dot, which creates a graph from the gprof data, nice! But, ultimately I'd like to visualize the data as a [flamegraph](https://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html), popularized by [Brendan Gregg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2603561/brendan-gregg). However, to my big surprise, I've not been able to find a tool to convert the gprof data into a format that flamegraph understands!?
Is anyone aware of such a utility? Or know how to do a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

`gprof` doesn't collect random stack samples, which is what flamegraphs display.
And here's what you might learn if you try [*flamegraphs*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771).