# Java-11 Profiling

Tags: java, performance, profiling, java-11, flamegraph

I want to do profiling for the Java-11 Spring hibernate application especially measure the time taken by each method, hibernate queries.

I did tried profiling using intellj but the flame graph dint have time taken for each method. Visual VM plugin in the intellj couldn't measure the Java-11 application. So,

1.Any other methods recommended to follow?.
2.Is there any approach to calculate time taken by each method.

Share your thoughts.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What you want to do, measure the time taken by each method, is not correct. Try [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771) instead.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: My application has multiple web services calls made by various methods. So I wanted to calculate time taken by each web services .

Comment: @prajkuma: I understand that's what you want. If on the other hand *you want to make it go faster*, that doesn't work. Random pausing *does* work, because it pinpoints the *activities* that are costing time. What I mean be an "activity" is not only the routines involved, but the precise lines of code involved, and the reasons for each one. If one of the reasons at one of the levels of a random call stack isn't strictly necessary and could be replaced with something simpler, *you get a speedup!* And notice - this has nothing to do with function times.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JProfiler, which has specific support for Spring and Hibernate, see the [screencast for profiling Spring applications](https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2023/01/profiling-jee-spring-applications/) and the [screencast for profiling Hibernate](https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2012/01/profiling-jpa-hibernate/). If you like flame graphs, [JProfiler has them as well](https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2022/11/using-flame-graphs-when-profiling-java-applications/).

JProfiler 14 can profile all Java versions starting with Java 1.5 up to the current Java version.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try these methods.